# Django Bad Request (400) on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 Server Running Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have a dozen Digital Ocean droplets setup with this same configuration with no issues, but for some reason I cannot get this one site to load - I keep getting a `Bad Request (400)` error when visiting the ip address of my server.  The site works fine on localhost though.

At this point I am not sure what and how much info to include here, so I've included the basics.

I am at my wits end..please help!

**Nginx Error Log**

```
2017/03/26 04:37:14 [error] 1626#1626: *129 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 82.113.98.143, server: 138.197.70.81, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/rooster/corbett/corbett.sock:/", host: "138.197.70.81:80"
2017/03/26 04:41:51 [error] 1626#1626: *325 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 50.118.145.87, server: 138.197.70.81, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/rooster/corbett/corbett.sock:/", host: "138.197.70.81"
2017/03/26 04:43:29 [error] 1626#1626: *409 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 31.29.63.51, server: 138.197.70.81, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/rooster/corbett/corbett.sock:/", host: "138.197.70.81"
2017/03/26 04:46:45 [error] 1626#1626: *581 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading upstream, client: 124.160.153.143, server: 138.197.70.81, request: "POST / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/rooster/corbett/corbett.sock:/", host: "138.197.70.81"
```

**Simple Site File**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 138.197.70.81;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/redrooster/corbett;
    }

    location /media/  {
       root  /home/redrooster/corbett;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/redrooster/corbett/corbett.sock;
    }
}
```

**Gunicorn Service File**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=redrooster
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/redrooster/corbett
ExecStart=/home/redrooster/corbett/venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/redrooster/corbett/corbett.sock crgapp.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**UPDATE 3/26/17 - This is one of my first Django sites done years ago, so I know this settings file is jacked up, but I will be rebuilding in the near future so now just trying to move from PythonAnywhere to Digital Ocean - just thought I'd mention :) **

**base.py**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
import os
import raven

RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'xxx',
    'release': raven.fetch_git_sha(os.path.dirname(os.pardir)),
}

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# SECRET KEY: keep the secret key used in production secret!
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)


SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'Corbett Restaurant Group <donotreply@xxx.com>'

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'adminsortable2',
    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'compressor',
    'ckeditor',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'taggit',
    'crgapp',
    'crgapp.listings',
    'crgapp.leases',
    'crgapp.press',
    'crgapp.apps.dashboard',
    'smart_selects',
    'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'crgapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'listings/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'leases/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'press/templates'),
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'apps/dashboard/templates'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
                'django.template.context_processors.static',
            ],
        },
    },
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'crgapp.wsgi.application'

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Tijuana'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

# Static Files
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

# Media Files
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True

# http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html#template-packs
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'

# Allauth & Social Accounts

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('account_login')
LOGOUT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_logout')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('nda_create')
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('account_login')
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'crgapp.apps.dashboard.forms.SignupForm'
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = False

# EMAIL SETUP
EMAIL_BACKEND = "sgbackend.SendGridBackend"
SENDGRID_API_KEY = "xxx"

# Ckeditor
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ["Format", "Bold", "Italic", "Underline", "Strike", "SpellChecker"],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', "Indent", "Outdent", 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter',
             'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock'],
            ["Image", "Table", "Link", "Unlink", "Anchor", "SectionLink", "Subscript", "Superscript"], ['Undo', 'Redo'], ["Source"],
            ["Maximize"]
        ],
        'autoParagraph': False,
        'allowedContent': True,
    }
}
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'
CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'pillow'
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'
```

**production.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .base import *

DEBUG = False

# PREPEND_WWW = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'xxx',
        'USER': 'xxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxx',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['corbettrestaurantgroup.com', 'www.corbettrestaurantgroup.com', '138.197.70.81']
```

**Nginx Access Log**

```
89.15.238.169 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:36 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
89.15.238.169 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:36 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
190.104.176.246 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:39 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
190.104.176.246 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:39 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
62.74.1.228 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:42 +0000] "\xAA\x133\xAC\xBE&\xCC\x18\xB4\x99\xC6\x8E\xCA\xC8\xAA\xF4\x95-\xF9\x1F\xF5;~\xD4\xDB\xC8\xF8\xE3\xE0\x0F\x8C\x90&\x9F\xBB\xD4\xF8\xD6J]\x7F_C|uC\xF0\xC7\x96\xC5\xC3\xC5\xFB\x02N\xCF-\x11L\xBC}\xEB\xCB\xE0\xA1\x94\xDF\xFB@\xF7\x10B\x9E\xC2\xEC\x7F6(\x14C\x81i\xA4\xD0\xC3\xB0\xC2c\xEETH\x0F\xFA\x89\xA3u$\xCE6\xF1\xBE\xEF\xDA\xF2\xD5\x94$\x84\xD1\x91B\x1F3\xD3\x15\x80\xEB\xE1\x0E\xA9i\x95\xB7\x84}\xA6\x0Eg\xD8f\xB3\xC9\xADk\xCCo\x5C\x7F\xDC\x1A\xC8`8u\x0B\xE8!\xC7\xD8,\xD5w\xDAd\x0B^!\x94xu\xB0f\xDB8\xE6\xF9(m\xEB\xE0A\x08,\x00\xAD>?\x9E\xBEz\x9B\x0E0\x09\x11\x8F\xF9d\xE7\xBC,wM\xAF\xD0HK\x0C\xEC" 400 182 "-" "-"
112.198.99.16 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:45 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.211.53.242 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:45 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
112.198.99.16 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:45 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
201.227.226.149 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:45 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
201.227.226.149 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:47 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
121.54.39.152 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:50 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
89.204.135.21 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:52 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
89.204.135.21 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:52 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
171.48.77.54 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:53 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
41.190.3.253 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:55 +0000] "POST /s/d/etisalat_ng#openModal/ HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "-"
159.0.142.150 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:41:58 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "-"
190.104.131.11 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:02 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
190.104.131.11 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:04 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.156.95.108 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:07 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 37 "-" "-"
82.114.168.157 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:08 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "-"
94.203.156.69 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:08 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "-"
190.104.176.188 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:10 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
190.104.176.188 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:10 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 400 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.211.53.241 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:11 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.211.53.241 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:12 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.156.103.225 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:13 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "-"
203.87.252.161 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:15 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
203.87.252.161 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:15 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.211.53.242 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:15 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
197.211.53.242 - - [26/Mar/2017:16:42:16 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 405 182 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.5)"
```

Comment: Share the code in `settings.py` as well.

Comment: Is your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` configured correctly?

Comment: @ShikharChauhan I added the base.py and production.py - this site works in local development as well as on Python Anywhere despite the obvious disarray of these files ( this was my first Django site many years ago)

Comment: Try adding your domain to [ALLOWED_HOSTS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) in `base.py`

Comment: @ShikharChauhan I did but now getting a 500 Error.  But my Sentry logs are now coming in and I have an actual error message  `settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.`

Comment: @StudioRooster Check if you have psycopg2 installed. Your request wasnt being addressed to because django did not identify the host. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: Yes, psycopg2 is installed - I was able to to do migrate and collectstatic, so I know that part is working.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan Well I have positive movement.  I moved all my database settings into virtualenv and set `ALLOWED_HOSTS='*'` but now getting a 500 Error...but, when I test with Gunicorn with `gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 crgapp.wsgi:application` and then in my browser visit `138.197.70.81:8000` the site loads

Comment: @ShikharChauhan Adding database info directly to base.py did the trick.  Now I need to figure out why my production.py file, which inherits from base.py isn't being used, but for now, I am fine with this hack or now.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @StudioRooster did you set `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` env variable to use `production.py`?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Yes and thats the crazy thing...everything else works from my production file.  This is an old install that I am transferring so it could be a number of things at this point...gotta love programming :)